# Audit logs to store only updated columns instead of storing all columns

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I had a table with 10 columns. I want to track the audit logs whenever someone is updating the table. But in the audit table, I want to have the column name, primary key, the old value of the updated column, the new value of the updated column, and the timestamp.

If more than one column is updated at a time, then I want those columns which are updated with the old and new values in the audit table instead of having all the old values and new values of all the columns which will be difficult to compare which exact column is updated.

Comment: See [here](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) or [here](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/)

Comment: but those links are giving all old and new values of all the columns. I want only updated ones. For ex. the table has three columns A, B, and C respectively. I updated column C. then in my audit table I have to see column name (C), old value, and the new value of that particular column only.

Comment: What if a column is syntactically updated but to the same value it already had?

Comment: we will compare the old and new values right, like it the old and new values should not be equal. if it is different then it should log in to the audit table